# how to condense multiple http redirect chains into one

Tags: wordpress, http-redirect

I am trying to make sense of this. A site that i am working on is showing a chain of redirects. To optimize the load times i want to reduce the number of redirects. I want to make them all to be a single redirect.

```
http.example.com > https.www.example.com
http.www.example.com > https.www.example.com
https.example.com > https.www.example.com
```

This site uses wordpress. I have tried looking at the .htaccess file but not really sure what i need to do to tackle this.

How can i address this redirect issues?

Answer (score 0):

Us your .htaccess file and put this in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.\(.*)$ [NC]
Rewrite ^/?(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```